# Typesetting Malayalam in xelatex & lualatex gives error

Tags: xetex, luatex, texlive, polyglossia

I'm new to Typesetting Malayalam. I tried compilating a simple code to pdf using XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{malayalam}
\setmainfont{[Rachana-Regular.ttf]}
\setlanghyphenmins{malayalam}{3}{4}
\linespread{1.2}
\begin{document}
വിഷയം:
\end{document}
```

(I've put `Rachana-Regular.ttf` in the same folder)

But compiling with `xelatex` gives this:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022/Termux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./r.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-11-02>
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/articl
e.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class

(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11
.clo))
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fo
ntspec.sty
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/
xparse/xparse.sty
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/ex
pl3.sty
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l
3backend-xetex.def)))
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fo
ntspec-xetex.sty
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fonten
c.sty)
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fo
ntspec.cfg)))
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia
/polyglossia.sty
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/et
oolbox.sty)
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/ma
kecmds.sty)
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xke
yval.sty
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/x
keyval.tex
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/x
kvutils.tex
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/k
eyval.tex))))
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ift
ex.sty)
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/
l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia
/gloss-latex.lde))
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia
/gloss-malayalam.ldf

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.3 
     \ProvidesFile{gloss-malayalam.ldf}[polyglossia: module for Malayalam]
?
```

And with `lualatex`:

```
~ lualatex r.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022/Termux)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./r.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
 L3 programming layer <2022-11-02>
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/articl
e.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class

(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11
.clo))
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fo
ntspec.sty
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/
xparse/xparse.sty
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/ex
pl3.sty
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l
3backend-luatex.def)))
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fo
ntspec-luatex.sty
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fonten
c.sty)
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fo
ntspec.cfg)))
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia
/polyglossia.sty
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/et
oolbox.sty)
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/ma
kecmds.sty)
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xke
yval.sty
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/x
keyval.tex
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/x
kvutils.tex
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/k
eyval.tex))))
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ift
ex.sty)
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/
l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase
/luatexbase.sty
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestac
k/ctablestack.sty))
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia
/gloss-latex.lde))
(/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia
/gloss-malayalam.ldf
Module polyglossia Warning: Language malayalam not found in language.dat.lua on
 input line 15
Module polyglossia Warning: Language malayalam not found in language.dat.lua on
 input line 15

Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `malayalam
'
(polyglossia)                I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead on i
nput line 15.

)

Package polyglossia Warning: id:ml on input line 6.

(./r.aux

! Package polyglossia Error: The current latin roman font does not contain the
"Malayalam" script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \malayalamfont with \newfontfamily c
ommand.

See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.3 \selectlanguage *{malayalam}

?
```

I'm not sure what this means. It seems there is some problem with polyglossia. How to fix this?
I'm using medium installation of Texlive in termux

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: I opened an issue about the stray U+FEFF https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/574.  But with lualatex it compiles fine for me, from you log it looks as if you didn't install a full texlive. Check if there are language related packages you can additionally install.

Answer (score 3):

Use LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX. In LuaLaTeX your document just works.

If you for some reason absolutely have to use XeLaTeX you can work around this issue by setting the catcode of U+FEFF to ignore (9) to ignore byte order marks.

Also note that the font name passed to `fontspec` should not be surrounded by square brackets. Doing so just makes things slower and can lead to weird bugs.

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\catcode"FEFF=9
\setdefaultlanguage{malayalam}
\setmainfont{Rachana-Regular.ttf}
\setlanghyphenmins{malayalam}{3}{4}
\linespread{1.2}
\begin{document}
വിഷയം:
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Could you elaborate on the U+FEFF topic?

Comment: It didn't work on lualatex too.. I've updated the question about it